# Mongodb query To sort blog posts based on how many views the post has got?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection called `BLOGS` in Mongodb. Using NodeJs, I need to display blogs entries on my website based on how many views it has got, in acsending or descending order.
How should I proceed?

Comment: Hi - what does your data look like? Are you keeping track of views as individual records? What does your query currently look like?

Comment: Actually I know how to do a query,,the problem I'm facing is to keeping track of unique views,,how do I do it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a standard query, you can use the sort method to order by a specific field:

for instance - something like:

```
db.blogs.find({}).sort({ views: 1 });

db.blogs.find({}).sort({ views: -1 });
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#order-documents-in-the-result-set

Here is how you would do it in Node.js using the Mongoose driver:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

In the passing options section, use a similar sort syntax:

```
// passing options
blogs.find({}, null, { sort: { views: 1 } });


// passing options and executes
blogs.find({}, null, { sort: { views: 1 } }, function (err, docs) {});
```

Comment: But what about the views..?

Comment: That would be in your query paramters, in the .find.  You could use the logical less than / greater than operators if you have minimum/maximums you are looking to query on.

Comment: Ok got it,,can u help me with the code,,for increment the view value for unique view

Comment: To increment the view count you would want to perform an update using the increment operator:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Comment: Oh awesome, got it..!

Comment: app.get("/blog/:Id",(req,res)=>{
   Blog.findbyId(req.params.id,(err,foundBlog)=>{
      If(err){
      Console.log(err);
     } else {
     foundBlog.update({$inc: {views:1}});
    res.render("blogpage",{blog:foundBlog});
  }
});
});

Comment: Y does the code not increment the views value

Comment: You can either modify the blog directly from the foundBlog property, like foundBlog.views += 1; and then save it like foungBlog.save(), or you can use the .updateOne function instead of findById. 

Blog.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { views: 1 } })

Comment: Thx,,It's working ,But wht abt the unique increment ,,like everytime I refresh page ,it increments the value

Comment: That's outside the scope of this question, but you may want to look into storing a user's IP address or user ID and only incrementing if the IP address is new.